# When we use apple map in mainland china then it's not showing correct location, is it possible to use Alibaba map in ios?

Tags: ios, apple-maps

In ios is it possible to use Alibaba map? As apple map sometimes not showing correct locations.
If possible please help to provide some links

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Relevant: [Why Every Map of China is Just Slightly Wrong (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9Di-UVC-_4)

Comment: sure! alibaba map named amap, but amap haven't english version api document. there is link https://lbs.amap.com/api/ios-sdk/summary

Comment: there is amap demo, https://github.com/cq0702/gaodeMapDemo

Comment: there is official demo, https://github.com/amapapi/iOS_Loc_Demo